# Displaying custom type errors in type families

Tags: haskell, ghc

GHC 8.0 has a feature for [user-defined type errors](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#custom-compile-time-errors). I'm trying that out, but I can't quite get it to do what I want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

data DoubleD
data IntD

type family CTypeOf x where
  CTypeOf (a,b) = EqCType (CTypeOf a) (CTypeOf b)
  CTypeOf Double = DoubleD
  CTypeOf Int = IntD

  CTypeOf a = TypeError (Text "Unsupported type: " :<>: ShowType a)

type family EqCType a b where
  EqCType a a = a
  EqCType a b = TypeError (Text "Pair error")

class (repr ~ CTypeOf r) => Dispatch' repr r
instance (CTypeOf r ~ DoubleD) => Dispatch' DoubleD r
instance (CTypeOf r ~ IntD) => Dispatch' IntD r

foo :: (Dispatch' (CTypeOf a) a) => Proxy a -> Int
foo _ = 3

main :: IO ()
--main = print $ foo (Proxy::Proxy (Int, Int))
--main = print $ foo (Proxy::Proxy (Int, Double))
--main = print $ foo (Proxy::Proxy Bool)
--main = print $ foo (Proxy::Proxy (Bool, Bool))
main = print $ foo (Proxy::Proxy (Bool, Double))
```

The first four definitions of `main` work like I expect:

1. compiles
2. error: `Pair error`
3. error: `Unsupported type: Bool`
4. error: `Unsupported type: Bool`

For the fifth definition, I *want* to display `Unsupported type: Bool`, but GHC shows:

5. error: `No instance for (Dispatch' (EqCType (TypeError ...) DoubleD) (Bool, Double))`

I'm confused why GHC got the first three errors correct, but isn't showing my type error on the final definition. I'm looking for a brief explanation of **why**, plus a workaround if possible. Is this just a limitation of the implementation of custom type errors?

Comment: [I think GHC is wrong here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12237).

Comment: @Cactus Thanks for reporting.